# Weak entity primary key

Tags: database, database-design

I have two entities `Business` and `Pack`. Businesses can have more than one pack.  And a pack can only have one business.

So, it looks like this,

**Business**

```
ID
```

**Pack**

```
Business_ID    Pack_ID
```

My questions are:

1. Could `Pack_ID` be a single auto-incremented primary key?
2. Or, could `Pack_ID` and `Business_id` together be a composite primary key? `Pack_ID` is auto-incremented for every `Business_Id`, so like this: `Business_Id=1 Pack_ID = 1,2,3`, `Business_Id=2 Pack_ID=1,2,3`
3. Which of the above is best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would almost always vote for the **single, auto-incremented** `Pack_ID`, mainly for two reasons:

**(1)** you can let the database handle the creation of the values (using e.g. `IDENTITY` in SQL Server or similar features in other RDBMS) - creating unique `Pack_ID` per each value of `Business_Id` is trickier to accomplish;

**(2)** foreign key relationships are always easier if you can just reference **one column** - instead of having to replicate two or three columns just because the PK of the table you're referencing is a compound PK